Confusion about the usefulness of martial law or a state emergency

Sheikh Hasina asked Delhi to 'attack Dhaka'


(...) Sheikh Hasina called that country's National Security Advisor Ajit Doval on the morning of August 5 and sought Delhi's intervention in Dhaka. Before seeking Delhi's help, she tried to impose martial law or a state of emergency in the country but failed. Because top military officials, including the Bangladesh Army Chief, rejected her proposal. (...)
(...) Sheikh Hasina called President Md. Shahabuddin Chuppu at Bangabhaban on August 4 and asked him to be ready to declare a state of emergency. She ordered the army chief to suppress the student and public protests by firing. Similarly, she also asked the air force chief to fire from a helicopter. But none of Sheikh Hasina's intentions or orders were implemented. In the end, she was given 45 minutes to pack her suitcases and go to a safe location to save her life.(...) (Translation by Google).

I don't get this.
What advantage would a declaration of martial law or a state emergency have given Sheikh Hasina during that volatile moment?

As stated in the Constitution, the purpose of state of emergency is to suspend constitutional rights. The quote in the question says directly:

She ordered the army chief to suppress the student and public protests by firing. Similarly, she also asked the air force chief to fire from a helicopter.

The state of emergency was clearly intended to provide legal cover for these orders.

The decision to declare martial law or a state of emergency often arises in moments of political turbulence, as these measures provide significant advantages to a leader seeking to maintain control. Sheikh Hasina’s alleged attempt to impose martial law or declare a state of emergency during a volatile political moment can be understood within this context. These tools, though extreme, are frequently used to consolidate power and suppress dissent in times of crisis.
A declaration of martial law or a state of emergency typically grants sweeping powers to the executive branch of the government. These measures often suspend normal constitutional procedures, allowing a leader to bypass parliamentary checks and other institutional restrictions. For Sheikh Hasina, this would have meant the ability to issue orders unilaterally, providing a legal and operational framework to crack down on widespread protests.
One immediate advantage of martial law is the ability to involve the military directly in governance and law enforcement. In such scenarios, the armed forces often assume control of maintaining public order, making it easier to suppress protests and stabilize a volatile situation through the use of force.
A state of emergency also offers tools to suppress public dissent through the imposition of curfews, restrictions on public gatherings, and limitations on press freedom. By implementing these measures, Sheikh Hasina could have justified the use of force against protesters and controlled the narrative around the unrest. Furthermore, actions taken under a state of emergency are often protected from future legal or political scrutiny, providing the government with a layer of immunity for controversial decisions made during the crisis.
Declaring a state of emergency can also serve as a symbolic move, projecting strength and control to both domestic and international audiences. For a leader facing political challenges, such a declaration signals an intention to retain power at all costs. It also disrupts the momentum of opposition forces, giving the government an opportunity to regroup and reassert control.
Another critical advantage of these measures lies in their ability to prevent leadership changes during times of instability. A state of emergency can delay or even cancel elections, halt parliamentary processes, and suppress efforts to oust a leader through legal or political means. For Sheikh Hasina, this would have been a way to safeguard her position in the face of growing resistance.
